# Estimate this expression $\sqrt{\sin(15/0.5)\times 5000-1}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Estimate $$\sqrt{\sin(15/0.5)\times 5000-1}?$$

I am quite sure what is the question asking me.

estimate $\sin(15/0.5)$ is quite difficult.

Comment: Are the angles in degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the series of $\sqrt{x^2-1}$
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}= x-\frac{1}{2x}+O(\frac{1}{x})^3$$
so
$$\sqrt{2500-1}=\sqrt{50^2-1}\approx 50-\frac{1}{100}=49.99$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{\sin(15/0.5)\times 5000-1}$

$\sqrt{\sin(30)\times 5000-1}$

Assuming it is $30^0$ degrees. (As $\sin 30 $ has a nice value)

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\times 5000-1}$= $\sqrt{2500-1}$= $\sqrt{2499}$= $\boxed{49.98}$

---

Edit: check the comment.

Comment: May be worth noting that to get an approximation of $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ manulay, one can use: $$ \sqrt{x^2-1} = x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} \approx x \big(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}\big) = x - \frac{1}{2x}$$ so for x=50 we should have $$ \sqrt{2499} \approx 50 - \frac{1}{100} = 49.99$$

Comment: awesome, I didn't knew this approximation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming angle in degrees

The question is pretty easy as $\frac{15}{0.5}$ comes to be equal to 30.

As we know sin(30) =$\frac{1}{2}$

The calculation boils down to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\times 5000-1}$

which is quite simple and comes to be 50( as question only asks a estimate)

---

Assuming angle in radians

sin(30)= sin(270) in degrees =-1(nearly)

which means $\sqrt {(-1) * 5000 -1}$

Negative under a bracket leads to complex solution and hence the answer here is $71i$